# Use of .htaccess hides phpmyadmin localhost folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, phpmyadmin

My problem is when I am using this .htaccess file in my root folder `nfs`, the folder becomes invisible.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/phpmyadmin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^details1/([0-9]+)/([0-9-]+)$  details1.php?cus_id=$1&ad_id=$2 [NC, L]
```

Again when I remove the below last line, then `nfs` folder becomes visible.

```
RewriteRule ^details1/([0-9]+)/([0-9-]+)$  details1.php?cus_id=$1&ad_id=$2 [NC, L]
```

I wanted to add url rewrite rule. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^details1/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) details1.php?cus_id=$1&ad_id=$2
```